# Missing material and textures after creating assetbundles in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, asset-pipeline

I was trying to use my character asset in Character customization project in place of the Male/Female asset by unity. When I am loading through asset bundle my character is partly visible, only its hair and shoes are visible. Generating material step went fine. By looking deeper in the project I found out in the class CreateAssetbundles.cs, at line

```
Debug.Log("Saved " + bundleName + " with " + (toinclude.Count - 2) + " materials");
```

The bundles other than the shoes and hair are taking 0 materials. This kind of clears that I am not creating the bundles properly. Am I missing any step? Is there is any fixed naming pattern for the material or assetbundle generation?

Also I am trying with some maya assets, with them I am not even able to generate material. And if I manually generate material, then assetbundles are not generating.

Moreover, I am not finding any documentation for this example project. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your asset bundle, make sure your script uses the BuildAssetBundleOptions.CollectDependencies and BuildAssetBundleOptions.CompleteAssets options.  This will cause the bundle to pull in all materials, textures, etc. when building the bundle.

See http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle.html?from=AssetBundle for reference.

Comment: Those two options are automatically turned on in 2019.3 and higher versions.